Calculating a partial dependency plot with prediction intervals for an SAR model in R
I am working with a spatial autoregressive model in R. I would like to create a partial dependency plot of the effect of predictor variables on the outcome (holding everything else constant). With regular lm models, I would create new data across a range of values of one predictor (e.g., while holding other predictors at their mean), and then use the predict() function with the option interval = "confidence" to get the confidence interval. My question is, how to do this with the SAR model? There is no such option to predict with this model that I know of.
library(spdep)
data(oldcol)
lw <- nb2listw(COL.nb, style="W") #listw object
mod <- errorsarlm(CRIME ~ INC + HOVAL, data=COL.OLD, lw) #SAR model

Here, I would like to generate partial dependency plots (e.g., of INC, and of HOVAL) with condfidence intervals (e.g., 95%).
I have a read a bunch of online articles to no avail, including the documentation of the the predict.sarlm function.
Thanks!

errorsarlm is now defunct in spdep and has been moved to spatialreg.

@Axeman, thanks for pointing that out. My question still remains -- is there any way to generating partial dependency plots from errorsarlm models in spatialreg? I still don't see a way. Thanks!

I think yes, using predict, but not with confidence intervals.

Are there any other ways to create confidence intervals from an SAR model from scratch? Or is there a reason it's not an option in the predict function (i.e., it's improper or something, based on the assumptions of such a model)?
